# Create new array in Javascript loop

Tags: javascript, loops, chart.js

Im working with chartJS to populate graphs using a large recordset.

Im creating an ArrayOfArrays like follows:

```
var arrayOfArrays = 
JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.organisationData))');
```

I am now trying to create multiple arrays to store the data to populate the graph. To do so I am doing the following:

```
 var array0=[]
 var array1=[]
 var array2=[]
 var array3=[] 
 ...etc...up to  var array17=[]
```

I populate each array like follows:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    array1.push(arrayOfArrays[i]['dataRows'][1]['dataCount']);
}
array1.push(arrayOfArrays[1]['dataRows'][1]['dataLabel']);  //Item 5 - Label


for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    array2.push(arrayOfArrays[i]['dataRows'][2]['dataCount']);
}
array2.push(arrayOfArrays[1]['dataRows'][2]['dataLabel']);//Item 5 - Label

etc..etc...repeated 17 times....
```

Then to populate the chart I'm doing..

```
var options = {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        datasets: [
            {
                label: @array0[5]",
                data: @array0
            },
            {
                label: @array1[5]",
                data: @array1
            },
            {
                label: @array2[5]",
                data: @array2
            }
            .....etc....etc.....17 times...



        ]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    reverse: false
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this? Instead of repeating everything 17 times can i create a loop that generates each of the arrays. Then populate those arrays and use them in chartJS.

Comment: Why not use an array that holds the 17 arrays?

Comment: @danzel your right....im complicating things as usual!